# Optimizing a query that uses index seek based on wrong estimates

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am joining two tables called Zasilka and Kapitola. Each one has a clustered index and Kapitola has also non clustered index with a column with which I am joining.

The query uses index seek because it expects only 1 row to be returned.

The statistics on both tables are updated.

I have tried to disable the index, then it uses merge join but it has to first order about 40000 rows, which takes a lot of resources.

Index column is mostly ordered but there are some cases when not. I just try to think about what would be the best strategy to join these tables and avoid order or seek.

And I do not know why it does not use non clustered index to join using merge.

[Exectuion plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPUWT.png)

[io statistics seek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUswI.png)
[io statistics merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aktmc.png)

Comment: Can you add the table DDL and query to your question?  In a Nested Loops Join the "Estimated Number of Rows" is per Execution, and the "Actual Number of Rows" is across all Executions.

Comment: Can you add the query to your post? And maybe upload the plan to pastetheplan.com (it's easier than parsing through an image).

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading the information in the showplan, I believe.  The estimate is per execution of the subtree. It estimates it will return 1 row per subtree execution and that it will execute the subtree 71,000 times.  (It doesn't estimate less than one).  Due to the containment assumption, it believes it will find a row when seeking (assumption of the optimizer based on usual customer behavior).  In actuality, you get 46,000 rows or so back.  So, the optimizer is working as expected in this case.

In the future, please post the query text, schema, and whole plan shape.  It is very hard to do more than guess when you take a screenshot with most of the plan shape covered up.